# nginx ingress controller don't reach backend service?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am currently trying to expose an kubernetes service via an ingress controller, but I cannot seem to so?
Who some odd reason does the host/path never resolve to the clusterIp and port that I want to use, eventhough this should have been resolved via my ingress controller and the ressource?...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-kubernetes
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-kubernetes
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-kubernetes
        image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller-conf
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress-lb
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccount: nginx
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-backend-service
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller-conf
            - --v=2
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
          - name: http 
            containerPort: 80
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: http
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      name: https 
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nginx
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - endpoints
  - nodes
  - pods
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - update
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-role
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
---
#Ingress ressource
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-hello
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.hello.com
    http:
      paths: 
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes
          servicePort: 80
---
##Default backend
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-backend-service
  labels:
    app: default-backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: default-backend
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: default-backend
  labels:
    app: default-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: default-backend  
  serviceName: default-backend-service
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: default-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: default-backend
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
---
```

I tried to make an MVP - but for some reason I can't resolve the path `dev.hello.com`
I want to use that to tell the ingress which service I want to connect to... but for some reason this never resolves to an ip address - it does not seem to hit anything?

Why? Is this incorrectly setup?

Answer (score 0):

The service for hello-kubernetes should not be of type `LoadBalancer` because you want the ingress to work as Loadbalancer. So change the service of hello-kubernetes to type `ClusterIP`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-kubernetes
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you exactly wants. You should be more precise what you exactly wants.

**1.** Ingress with ClusterIP.

Like Arghya Sadhu wrote, as you are using `Ingress` you don't need to specify [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer).

**2.** Ingress with `NodePort`

Keep in mind that you can also use `NodePort` with `Ingress`. Good explenation and example can be found [here](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html).

**3.** Ingress YAML
As per official [Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) minimal Ingress resources looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

In your Ingress I couldn't find `spec.rules.http.paths.path`.

**4.** IP of LoadBalancer

Also very important is where are you have your cluster. If you are using `On-Prem` like GKE, AWS, AZURE, etc. your `LoadBalancer` will automatically get `externalIP` which allow you to connect to your cluster from outside. However, if you are using local machine you will need to use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

In addition, please take a look at kubernetes docs about [Connect a Front End to a Back End Using a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/).

Also please check [this tutorial](https://www.ovh.com/blog/getting-external-traffic-into-kubernetes-clusterip-nodeport-loadbalancer-and-ingress/), it might help you.